# Using FCM for instant messaging chat app python

Tags: python, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

Is it possible to use Firebase Cloud Messaging for an instant messaging with python? All I've found so far is about sending notifications or using the admin SDK.

Comment: There is an official SDK for Python https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-python

Comment: That's the admin SDK, not for instant messaging between users

Comment: I was assuming you use Python program as a chat server -- that's the common use case. If you want to use it a chat client, there is currently no official support. You can still use [HTTP API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/first-message#http_post_request) to send FCM message. But there is no documented way to receive/listen for message (only for web & mobile)

Comment: So I could use FCM to allow users to message between each other? Using the admin SDK? How does this work, is there a python tutorial for it somewhere?